# c# fill checkelistbox from combobox SQL

Tags: c#, sql, combobox, checkedlistbox

I have ha winform app in c# witch gets values from SQL server database. 
I can get the values i want to apear in the `combobox` but depending on the selection made i want to show the corresponding sql lines in the `checkedcombobox` for the user to select the desired one.
The code i have is: (to fill the combobox)

```
    SqlDataAdapter SDA = new SqlDataAdapter("select distinct desempenho from vidros", con);
    DataTable DTT = new DataTable();
    SDA.Fill(DTT);
    desempenho.Items.Clear();
    foreach (DataRow ROW in DTT.Rows)
    {
        desempenho.Items.Add(ROW["desempenho"].ToString());
    }
```

And: (to display the selected line in the checkedcombobox) witch is not working.

```
 private void checkedListBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter("select desc from vidros where desempenho ='" + desempenho.Text + "'", con);
            DataTable DTT = new DataTable();
            sda.Fill(DTT);
            checkedListBox1.Items.Clear();
            foreach (DataRow AB in DTT.Rows)
            {
                checkedListBox1.Items.Add(AB["desc"].ToString());
            }
        }
```

Is this the best way to give the user several items to chose from? 
Does anyone know what the problem might be with the code?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: And what doesn't work? Can you explain what problem do you have with this code?

Comment: @Steve sorry for the bad explanation. the problem i have is that when i select an item from the combobox nothing appears in the checkedlistbox.

Comment: Are you sure to not have an exception thrown? That DESC field name is a reserved keyword and used as is should trigger an exception.

Comment: I suggest to use the debugger to check if the event handler is really called and what is the value of the combobox text at the event code.

Comment: Why your code is in selectedindexchanged event of listbox? It should be in selectedindexchanged of combobox

Comment: @Chetan Ranpariya omg i dont know how i missed it, problem solved. 
If you want answer the question and i´ll mark it as answered

Comment: @septaug Good that the issue is resolved. I have posted the answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the code for binding listbox is put at incorrect place.
If you want to bind listbox based on the selected item of combobox box, you need to write that logic in the SelectedIndexChanged event of the combobox.

If you move your code to SelectedIndexChanged event handler of combobox as following.

```
private void desempenho_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter("select desc from vidros where desempenho ='" + desempenho.Text + "'", con);
        DataTable DTT = new DataTable();
        sda.Fill(DTT);
        checkedListBox1.Items.Clear();
        foreach (DataRow AB in DTT.Rows)
        {
            checkedListBox1.Items.Add(AB["desc"].ToString());
        }
    }
```

Attach this handler to the SelectedIndexChanged event of the handler and it should solve the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Sooner or later this error happens to everyone.

DESC is a reserved keyword in practically any existant database system. It is used in the ORDER BY clause to have the results ordered descending.

So if you really have a field named in that way (better change that name as soon as possible) you need to enclose it in the escaping characters (Sql Server uses the square brakets)

```
SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(@"select [desc] 
       from vidros where desempenho ='" + desempenho.Text + "'", con);
```

Said that I also recommend to use a parameterized query. In your case you should be relatively safe but it is better to avoid totally any possibility of sql injection

```
SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(@"select [desc] 
       from vidros where desempenho = @emp", con);
sda.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add("@emp", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = desempenho.Text;
 .....
```

Comment: hi thanks for the help, unfortunately the checkedlistbox still displays no restults.